# Grape hash params with dynamic key names

Tags: ruby, ruby-grape

Is it possible to specify grape parameters when keys are unknown (because they are identifiers, e.g. a name or an ID)

```
{
  "pascal" => {"property_1" => 1234, "property_2" => 5678},
  "another name" => {"property_1" => 1234, "property_2" => 5678}
}
```

So I want the params to be a Hash where they key is a String (preferrably validated with a regexp) and the value is yet another hash.

Comment: I don't think so. It seems to use the key as is, not as a proc or regex.

Comment: What's wrong with `{ "name": "pascal", "property_1": 1234, "property_2": 5678 }`?

Comment: Stefan is right, dynamic JSON keys are always awful to work with (and kind of defeat the purpose of using JSON), you should avoid them if you can

Comment: @stefan nothing wrong with your proposal. It is just the way it is and actually I prefer with the identifier of the record as key (because i'll need to add stuff to it later in)

Answer (score 0):

As @stefan and @Ideld pointed out: there is no way to do what I asked for and the recommended way is to use a format like:

```
  [
    { "name": "pascal", "property_1": 1234, "property_2": 5678 },
    { "name": "another_name", "property_1": 1234, "property_2": 5678 }
   ]
```

instead.